# How get particular value from loaded log4j config at runtime?

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j

After log4j is loaded it resolve properties from it's config, for example

```
myProperty = ${system_var_name}/someValue
```

is resolved to system variable with `system_var_name` plus `/someValue` string. The question is - how get `myProperty` resolved value from log4j config? E.g. where does log4j stores all loaded and resolved properties?

Answer (score 0):

The log4j properties file is in the resources folder. You can access this file through this:

```
PropertyResourceBundle bundle = (PropertyResourceBundle)
PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("log4j");
String value= bundle.getString("myProperty");
```

Comment: Ok and how get `PropertyResourceBundle`?